# Spring MVC REST api not consuming json in chrome web client

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have an angularjs spring web app that returns a json. This is the url

```
http://localhost:8080/AngularJSPostFormSpringMVC/
```

[image]

The above is the output of the json url.

When I luanch the url in chrome web client it does not consume json even though it returns a status of 200 : 0k.

This is the out put

[image]

This is my controller code

```
public class SpringMVCController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/PostFormData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Person PostService(@RequestBody Person person) {

        return person;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/PostFormDataByParam", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Person PostFormDataByParam(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        person.setName(request.getParameter("location"));
        person.setName(request.getParameter("phone"));
        return person;
    }
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: I have added jackson dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: Not clear what you do want.

Comment: I want to be able to fetch to fetch json on a post method using chrome web client

Comment: Let me be clear, what you exactly want is submit your form data to your controller method `PostService`, and bind these data to your entity `Person`, am I all right?

Comment: And receive them as a JSON array. Just look at @ResquestBody

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110890/discussion-between-reno-and-jng).

Answer (score 0):

create model

```
public class Person {

private int name;
private String location;
private String phone;

getter setter ...
```

dependencies

```
<!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/PostFormDataByParam", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Person PostFormDataByParam(@RequestBody Person person, HttpServletRequest request) {

    person.get ...

    return person;
}
```

good luck ~

Answer (score 0):

Change type of parameter define in method `PostService`, like this;)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/PostFormData", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody
Person PostService(@RequestBody Person[] person) {

    return person[0];
}
```

Comment: The return statement throws an exception

Comment: Could not return json.

Comment: @JnG I've done some modification of your project, check my [Dropbox-AngularJSPostFormSpringMVC](https://www.dropbox.com/s/foelt0dmrchtq1t/AngularJSPostFormSpringMVC.zip?dl=0), and it worked properly in my Eclipse.